# XSL Display first letter of Node after a Space (If a space exists)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a node in my XML for **First Name** which includes the middle initial IF the middle initial exists.  (the database that feeds the XML does not have a Middle Initial field).

**Examples**:

```
<billing-firstname>Nicholas M.</billing-firstname>
<billing-firstname>Timothy</billing-firstname>
```

I want to be able to display this as just the initials.

**Output Examples**:

```
N. M.
T.
```

I already know how to snag the first character of the node, just not how to split it up w/ First Initial then Middle initial IF it exists.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(billing-firstname,1,1)" />
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="billing-firstname">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' ')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,1), '. ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML** (wrapped in a single top element to make it well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <billing-firstname>Nicholas M.</billing-firstname>
    <billing-firstname>Timothy</billing-firstname>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
N. M. 
T.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0 (with XPath 2.0), you could use a combination of `for`, `tokenize`, `substring`, `concat`, and `string-join`...

```
string-join(for $name in tokenize(normalize-space(),'\s') return concat(substring($name,1,1),'.'),' ')
```

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <billing-firstname>Nicholas M.</billing-firstname>
    <billing-firstname>Timothy</billing-firstname>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="billing-firstname">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join(for $name in tokenize(normalize-space(),'\s') return concat(substring($name,1,1),'.'),' ')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <billing-firstname>N. M.</billing-firstname>
   <billing-firstname>T.</billing-firstname>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will be testing this out within my project later today.  (Stay tuned)

Comment: I was already inside a loop, and running this gave me the first character of every item / column of data I selected within a table I coded.